# Printer log expanded info

Tags: c#, windows

I have built one small piece of software to get and save printers log details. I am reading Windows System Eventlog to get data of each print job sent to the print queue. After studing some commercial software, I can see they get more info that I can get from System Eventlog as paper size, number of copies and grayscale.

Is there any other way to get those print jobs details?

Comment: They probably don't use the Windows EventLog as information source, but hook into the [printer driver architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff559887(v=vs.85).aspx) somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You can write driver software or a service that either is installed as a printer driver or hooks into the driver's communication interface to read and save what exactly happens as the user is printing.

Comment: Must I hook into each printer or I'll receive all print jobs info in one place?